# How to rebind SwipeMenuListView onMenuItemClick items after filtering data?

Tags: android, listview

I've got fragment with SwipeMenuListView. Data comes from API. I'm binding buttons of SwipeMenuList in fragment and sending objects to Adapter to get 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vegj.png)

Everything is fine

But after filtering listview buttons are broken. When I press Profile button in filtered listview, app opens wrong profile
[Filtered data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6pVd.png)

So my question is how to update position of buttons?

notifyDataSetChanged and invalidateViews don't work for me.

```
public void setupSwipeList() {
    adapter = new SearchCardAdapter(getContext(), arrayList, a);
    final SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {

        @Override
        public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
            // create "open" item
            SwipeMenuItem profileItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                    getContext());
            // set item background
            profileItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(38, 153, 251)));
            // set item width
            profileItem.setWidth(300);
            // set item title
            profileItem.setTitle("Profile");
            // set item title fontsize
            profileItem.setTitleSize(18);
            profileItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_profile);
            // set item title font color
            profileItem.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
            // add to menu
            menu.addMenuItem(profileItem);
            SwipeMenuItem phoneItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                    getContext());
            // set item background
            phoneItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(38, 153, 251)));
            // set item width
            phoneItem.setWidth(300);
            // set item title
            phoneItem.setTitle("Mobile call");
            // set item title fontsize
            phoneItem.setTitleSize(18);
            phoneItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_phone);
            // set item title font color
            phoneItem.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
            // add to menu
            menu.addMenuItem(phoneItem);

            // create "delete" item
            SwipeMenuItem requestItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                    getContext());
            // set item background
            requestItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(38, 153, 251)));
            // set item width
            requestItem.setWidth(300);
            // set item title
            requestItem.setTitle("Request");
            // set item title fontsize
            requestItem.setTitleSize(18);
            requestItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_request);
            // set item title font color
            requestItem.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
            // add to menu
            menu.addMenuItem(requestItem);
        }
    };


    // Right
    listView.setSwipeDirection(SwipeMenuListView.DIRECTION_RIGHT);
    // Left
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            listView.smoothOpenMenu(i);
        }
    });
    listView.setSwipeDirection(SwipeMenuListView.DIRECTION_LEFT);
    listView.setMenuCreator(creator);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    listView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    // open
                    SpecialistFragment postobj = new SpecialistFragment();
                    bundle.putString("spec_id", arrayList.get(position).getId());
                    bundle.putString("phone", arrayList.get(position).getPhone());
                    postobj.setArguments(bundle);
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, postobj).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CALL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "+" + arrayList.get(position).getPhone()));
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SendRequestFragment obj = new SendRequestFragment();
                    bundle.putString("spec_id", arrayList.get(position).getId());
                    bundle.putString("spec_name", arrayList.get(position).getName());
                    bundle.putSerializable("categories", arrayList.get(position).getCategories());
                    bundle.putSerializable("districts", arrayList.get(position).getDistricts());
                    obj.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, obj).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    break;
            }
            // false : close the menu; true : not close the menu
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was because I had called `arrayList.get(position)` instead of  `adapter.getItem(position)`

When listView was filtered, adapter had another filtered data and it's not connected with SwipeMenuListView. So we should call `adapter.getItem(position)` to get relevant data.

```
listView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    // open
                    SpecialistFragment postobj = new SpecialistFragment();
                    bundle.putString("spec_id", adapter.getItem(position).getId());
                    bundle.putString("phone", adapter.getItem(position).getPhone());
                    postobj.setArguments(bundle);
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, postobj).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CALL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "+" + adapter.getItem(position).getPhone()));
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SendRequestFragment obj = new SendRequestFragment();
                    bundle.putString("spec_id", adapter.getItem(position).getId());
                    bundle.putString("spec_name", adapter.getItem(position).getName());
                    bundle.putSerializable("categories", adapter.getItem(position).getCategories());
                    bundle.putSerializable("districts", adapter.getItem(position).getDistricts());
                    obj.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, obj).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    break;
            }
            // false : close the menu; true : not close the menu
            return false;
        }
    });
```